# Angular6/Typescript - Add Object into Array of another Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, push

I need to push an Object into an array which contains another array by writing the ID into a textfield.How to use methods with arrays in arrays?

Demo: https://angular-flj24f.stackblitz.io

Classes:

```
 class Food {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    preis: number;
    art: string;
}

class Foodplan {
    id: number;
    foodPerWeek: number[] = new Array(5);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the stackblitz, it looks like the `foodPlan` array has only one element, which has index 0.  To add to the list of foods in that element, you would do something like this:

```
this.foodPlan[0].essenProWoche.push(id);
```

See [this updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vc7tws).  In the future, if you add a control to add multiple elements to the `foodPlan` array, then you'll need to know which one you are adding the food to and use the appropriate index.